# Flutter listview with Map instead of List

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to display the contents of my `HashMap` values in a `ListView.builder` widget. Is there a way to do this? With a `List` I could simply use the index, but how would that work with a `HashMap` without making a `List` out of it? 
The keys of the map are strings and the values are maps with the data to display.

Answer (score 90):

Its a little late but You could also try this.
Map values = snapshot.data;

```
return new ListView.builder(
  itemCount: values.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    String key = values.keys.elementAt(index);
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("$key"),
          subtitle: new Text("${values[key]}"),
        ),
        new Divider(
          height: 2.0,
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

for a more detailed example check this out
https://kodestat.gitbook.io/flutter/39-flutter-listviewbuilder-using-dart-maps

Answer (score 30):

Just make a list from the keys and then get the value using the index to get the map key and use it to get the map value

```dart
var keys = myMap.keys.toList();
var val = myMap[keys[idx]];
```

Comment: But I'm constantly changing the Map. I'd prefer not to create a list every time when I'm adding data.

Comment: Every time you change your map, you're calling setState() anyway, I presume? If so, you probably don't need to worry about calling keys.toList().

Comment: There is no way to access elements of a map by index. I don't think there are other map implementations that would allow that.

Comment: What is idx in this example?

Comment: The position of the element you want to access.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 10):

it is possible, you can do something like this

```
  map.forEach((key, value) {
        // here you can write your logic using "Value object",
       // make new object of your list view item and
       // add it to it's  builder list using 

       setState(() {
          _builderList.insert(0, itemObject);
       });

   });
```

or you can try

```
 final list = map.values.toList(growable: {true/false});
// play with your list
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use inside the listview builder yourlistname[index ]['keyname' ], that works for me.

Comment: Is it ideal? I have no idea ! Does it work? Yes !! Thank you