# Get a list out of map result from a rest call

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the following response from my NoSql database.
It is of type InternalLinkedHashMap.

```
    // key       // value
{
    "42514738" : "iohuahges",
    "25498724" : "hiuasfhyd",
    "24257+62" : "opiasurj",
    "35842942" : "ftysadyg",
    "98472442" : "iouyaerj"
}
```

I want to use these values to construct a ListView.
But the above is not a list and I will not be able to know the keys in the above map beforehand.
Thus even though the following would work (String s assignment below), I can't do it in runtime cos I have no idea on what the keys will be.

How can I get an index out of the above result?

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: methodReturningAboveMap(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // want to use index something like snapshot.data['collection'][0] and get get first key value and so on. 
                String s = snapshot.data['collection']['42514738']; // will work but can't do it as mentioned above 
            },
        );
    },
),
```

Comment: checkout [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856559/flutter-listview-with-map-instead-of-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856559/flutter-listview-with-map-instead-of-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract your data and cast it as a Map<String, dynamic> (for type safety)

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data['collection'];
```

Then in your ListView, you can get the index by using

```
String key = data.keys.elementAt(index);
```

Then access its value using

```
String value = data[key];
```