# populating list with another list in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I have a list of object and I want populate the list with another dynamic list using for each , so when I try to do so only the last value from the dynamic list is added to the other list..

some one please help

```
 var keylist =[1,2] ;
 for (var key in keylist) {

_devchanged=[



   Employeemodal(
   
       developer: key
   
    
       )

       ];
        }
```

Comment: I often use Map rather then list in list. Yu can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856559/flutter-listview-with-map-instead-of-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.add` like this

```
var keylist =[1,2] ;
List<Employeemodal> _devchanged = [];

 for (var key in keylist) {
    _devchanged.add(Employeemodal(developer: key));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much brother.                                                                                                                       List<Employeemodal> _devchanged = [];  initialisation does the trick right. i tried list.add but it always gave me unecxpected null value error.